# In the phrase 「褒められたものではない」, why is 「褒められた」 in past tense (as opposed to present tense 「褒められる」)?

Tags: grammar, tense, potential-form, aspect

For reference, there's an entry in 実用日本語表現辞典: [褒められたものではない](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%A4%92%E3%82%81%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18600/7810

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned in the related post linked in the comments above by @broken headphones, this「た」isn't being used to imply past tense.

Past tense is a common reason for using 「た」, but in this case I think the following definition from デジタル大辞泉 applies:

[３] 実現していない動作・状態を仮に実現したと考えていう意を表す。

So,

- 「褒められ**た**ものではない」

is establishing the hypothetical circumstance of something being praiseworthy,「褒められたもの」, and then negating that with ではない.

This た might be the same as the た in「～したら」and seems similar to the way the English Subjunctive Tense often ends up looking like the past tense, like "If he *was* taller", etc.

Here are some other ways of using the same construct:

- その値段では**払えた**ものではない - There's no way (anyone) **would pay** that price
- 歩いていたら**帰れた**ものではない - There's no way (you) **could walk** back

This grammar is used in giving a very strong and unquestionable opinion in a *matter-of-fact* way that whatever it is *could not possibly* be done.

In both cases the form of the verb used is

> 可能（払{はら}**え**）+ 完了・仮定（**た**）+ ものではない

This is a strong phrase indicating something like 払{はら}うことは到底{とうてい}できない, emphasizing that there is "*no way*" that payment is possible.

Using 褒められ**る**・払え**る**・帰れ**る** instead of「た」would break the structure above and the meaning would be difficult to understand.

Comment: I would very much appreciate any constructive criticism if I'm mistaken on this.

Comment: Looks reasonable to me; not sure why people down-voted.