# 母ちゃんも心配でたまったもんじゃない

Tags: translation

Another がばいばあちゃん question. One sentence ends in もんじゃない which I understand as, 「〜すべきではない（忠告など）」. But it's strange the verb preceding it should be in past tense.

Here is the sentence in context.

> 困ったことに、小学校に入る頃になると、俺はチョロチョロと夜中に家を抜け出しては、かあちゃんの店にでかけて行くようになったのだ。
>
> さっきも書いたように周りはスラム街である。
>
> そんなところを、ちっこい俺がチョロチョロやって来るのだから、**かあちゃんも心配でたまったもんじゃない**。

I assume the translation would be something along the lines of: "As I came to such a place and darted around, mama got terribly worried - a thing that was regrettably no good for her."

It would good if I could understand how past tense verbs can be used with もんじゃない.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I think I have answered my own question and have given an explanation below with the appropriate translation of the passage in question.

Comment: `たっまたもんじゃない` -> 「た**まっ**たもんじゃない」ですよね？

Comment: Yes, that's right. I corrected it. My mistake.

Comment: Partly related, maybe...? : https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18600/9831

Comment: I found the answer here. http://www.weblio.jp/content/たまったもんじゃない Basically, it's like tamaranai, but stronger.

Comment: おお～ You found the answer (^_^) Yes, 心配でたまったもんじゃない is an emphatic way of saying 心配でたまらない, とても心配だ.

Answer (score 2):

The expression たまったもんじゃない is [similar to たまらない but *stronger*](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9F%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%82%E3%82%93%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84).

So the translation would be something like:

> When I entered primary school, a new trouble developed. I used to sneak out of the house at night and scurry through the streets on my way to her shop. As I mentioned earlier, the area around my house was a slum. Knowing this was no place for a little boy, Mama got worried sick and couldn't take it any longer.