# I am trying to figure out what this sentence means but can't figure out part of it

Tags: translation

確かに、女にもてるのもいいが、じらされる方はたまったもんじゃねぇ

I think the first part says something like, it is certainly nice to have a girlfriend/wife but I can't figure out the rest. Please help...

Comment: For the usage/meaning of ～たものじゃない: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18615/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 確かに、女にもてるのもいいが、じらされる方はたまったもんじゃねぇ

- 女にもてる: to be popular among women
- じらす: to tease (a person)
- じらされる方 is じらされる側: the side that is teased
- たまったもんじゃねえ is 堪｛たま｝ったものじゃない or 堪｛たま｝らない, which is 我慢｛がまん｝できない/耐｛た｝えられない: can't stand (some situation)
- ***some situation** in *can't stand some situation* might be 待たされること *to be kept waiting*.

The whole meaning is like:
*It is certainly nice to be popular among women but I who am teased can't stand being made to wait*.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for that excellent breakdown of the sentence structure. How do you get from たまったものじゃない to 我慢がまんできない/耐たええられない?

Comment: @Noob: たまったものじゃない is たまらない, which is written in kanji as 堪｛たま｝らない. The meaning of 堪｛たま｝らない  is 〈耐｛た｝えられない〉 cannot stand; be unable to bear [put up with]; be unbearable; be unendurable. Thank you!